# Subtract Elements of two Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two Lists:
`L = {1,2,3,4,5}`
and `K = {1,4}`.

I would like to delete the elements of `K` (1,4) from the List `L`, so that the resulting List will be `R = {2,3,5}`.

Please can someone assist and help?

Comment: Check `Complement`, `DeleteCases` and friends.

Comment: Oh thank you very much @Kuba! I will try to search better next time! Please how can I remove my question?

Comment: You don't need too. It will stay here as a road sign to the main topic.